# connecting to a ros master

Tags: android, nodes, ping, ros

I downloaded ros-indego in linux 14.04 and I followed this link in order to publish the position of the phone to ros : connecting to a ros master

http://wiki.ros.org/android_sensors_driver/Tutorials/Connecting%20to%20a%20ROS%20Master

I cant find the node `/android_sensors_driver` 
I found `/android_sensors_driver_nav_sat_fix` and others

I pined this node `/android_sensors_driver`

then I tried echo but it didnt work ??

what should I do ?

Comment: Hey....I am the Travelling Salesman. It's my pleasure to meet the Travelling Saleswoman :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting the ROS_MASTER_URI?

This must be done on the computer, in the same terminal window as you then run roscore in.
Ex: My laptop has IP 192.168.1.2

So I must do:

`export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.2:11311/`

`export ROS_IP=192.168.1.2`

`roscore`